# Running Ubuntu on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon gen7

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

Sadly my Thinkpad T430s suffered a disk crash yesterday, so I'm in the market for a new computer (it was getting old anyway...).

I'm quite happy with running Thinkpad - my only issue has been battery life, which has been sub-par on the T430s. In any case, I'm considering the X1 Carbon gen7, but I've found various threads about problems with audio, microphone, wifi, battery life - but at the same time, the laptop is listed as "certified pre-install" at ubuntu.com. I understand the fingerprint reader won't work, but that is not an issue for me.

Are all these other quirks straightened out, or will I have much grief running Ubuntu on this laptop? Would the gen6 be a safer bet (although I understand that the speakers are much worse on that model)?

Answer (score 0):

Got an X1 Carbon G7 and using Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.
Loving the laptop inside out, weight, performance and build quality is fantastic.

Have issues with Microphone not detected, Function keys and couple other tweaks that I had to do along the way in order for it to work. I have got a touch screen, due to this battery life is below par. Not an issue for me but something to consider. Thinking of installing tlp to increase battery life.

Though it's certified preinstall but not in my case. Though I have read many posts of similar models working just out of the box.

I must say you have to spend some time in order for it to work, I just love the laptop but you know you're lucky if thing works out of the box for you.

Good luck.